# Issue warning on template instantiation based on template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang++, gcc-warning

We want to issue a compiler warning, if a user of our headers instantiates a template with certain templated types, which we did so far by template specialization:

```
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, template <typename...> class CONTAINER>
struct select_container {
  using _t =
      CONTAINER<T>;  // we don't have custom allocators for most containers
};

template <typename T>
struct select_container<T, std::vector> {
  using _t = std::vector<T>;  // meant for custom allocator
};

template <typename T>
struct select_container<T, std::deque> {
  using _t = std::deque<T>;  // custom allocator should also go here
  [[deprecated("We won't stop you from using deque, but please think twice "
               "(link to wiki).")]]
  constexpr static inline int __bad() {
    return 0;
  }
  enum { _bad = __bad() };
};

int foo() {
  select_container<int, std::vector>::_t vector_version;
  // select_container<int, std::deque>::_t deque_version;
  return vector_version[0];
}
```

This does the job with g++7 (warning gets issued when `deque_version` is in the code, and issues no warning as long as it's commented out). However, with g++-8 and clang++ 5 to 8 the warning gets always issued, even when no `select_container` is instantiated (i.e. when removing `foo` from the source). [See on compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/AGhMkA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the attribute on the alias:

```
template <typename T>
struct  select_container<T, std::deque> {
  using _t [[deprecated("We won't stop you from using deque, but please think twice "
               "(link to wiki).")]] = std::deque<T>;  // custom allocator should also go here
};
```

This works on both gcc and clang trunk. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5A9Jce).

Comment: The link to compiler-explorer does not contain the code you posted here (attribute on the outer struct, not on the _t alias).